# Cauchy Integral Theorem problem (lack of understanding)

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

First of all i was asked to evaluate this integral

$\int_\gamma \frac{2z}{(z-1)(z-3)} dz$ where $\gamma (t) = 2e^{it}$ for $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$.

Now I thought I would have to calculate this integral by means of partial fractions and then use Cauchy's integral formula on each part, but the solutions i have somehow reduce the integral, and apparently its due to the parameterisation (i.e. a circle of radius 2) and $(z-3)$ not being in the circe? I'm not sure but i lack understanding.

Also, following on from this, I just come across another question which I cannot answer due to the lack of understanding from the above. I have been asked to calculate $\int_\gamma f dz$ with $f(z) = \frac{1}{z-a}$ and where $\gamma$ is the paramterisation of some closed path. I have to consider $\textbf{both}$ cases when a lies inside the closed path and outside the closed path. So I am sure they're related but again I don't know how a being outside the parameterisation affects the integral.

The solution i have:

As $\frac{2z}{z-3}$ holomorphic on $\overline{\mathbb{B}(0,2)}$, we get by Cauchy's integral formula

$\int_\gamma \frac{2z}{(z-1)(z-3)} dz = 2\pi i[\frac{2z}{z-3}]$ (this seems to be evaluated somewhere but the handwriting becomes illegible), and the answer they get is $2\pi i$.

Comment: Regarding the second question, you should read the cauchy's integral formula statement. Perhaps consider posting your version of the statement in the question. As for the first one, partial fractions seems like the way to go. Please post the solution you have.

Comment: `this seems to be evaluated somewhere` At $z = 1$, hopefully. And the answer you should get is $-2\pi i$, since $\frac{2\cdot1}{1-3} = -1$.

Comment: I thought so, i guess the answer sheet is wrong. But my question is why is it simply evaluated at z-3? what happened to the (z-1) part?

Comment: @user65972 Can you post your version of the cauchy's integral formula statement, please?

Comment: Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ a bounded open subset and $f\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic. Pick $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and let $C \subset \Omega$ be a closed curve such that there is an $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that $\overline{\mathbb{B}(z_0,\epsilon_0)} \subset \Omega$ and there is a region $E \subset \Omega$ such that $\partial E = C \cup \partial \mathbb{B}(z_0,\epsilon_0)$  Then  $f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} dz$ (denoted by CI$_0$.

Comment: @user65972 For the first one use $f(z)=\dfrac{2z}{z-3}$ and $z_0=1$. In view of this, what don't you understand?

Comment: Ok well i just found a good textbook, and from what i understand we get a singularity when the denominator is zero but the numerator is non zero. Now we have a singularity at z=1 and z=3. Note that the numerator is non zero for both of these values. Now since our parameterisation is a circle of radius 2, the singularity at z=1 lies inside the circle. But i'm sure where to go from here..

Comment: I'm not sure why $f(z) = \frac{2z}{z-3}$ of all a sudden

Comment: @user65972 Simply because $\displaystyle \int_\gamma \dfrac{2z}{(z-1)(z-3)} \mathrm dz=\int_\gamma \dfrac{\frac{2z}{z-3}}{z-1} \mathrm dz.$ Does this make sense?

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally understand it now.

Comment: @user65972 No problem. It would be good if you posted an answer to the question, so this doesn't come up as unanswered. This is perfectly acceptable. For the second question, use equation $(12)$ in [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyIntegralFormula.html) link. Let me also remind you of my first comment.

Comment: ok thank you and thank you again.